# Connection String Not Properly Initialized VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two methods that access a local database.  They are identical except for one accesses one table, and the other another table.  The tables are the same.

Here is the code that works:

```
public void populateClientDict(SqlConnection conn)
{
            Dictionary<string, string> clientDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                using (conn)
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                      @"SELECT ClientDirName, ClientEmailDomain FROM ClientTable;",
                      conn);
                    conn.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string clientDir = reader.GetString(0);
                            string clientEmail = reader.GetString(1);
                            clientDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No rows found in ClientTable", "Rows Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
}
```

Here is what the conn argument is equivalent to in the two functions: `SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);` and connString is `private string connString = @"Server=.;User Id=cshenkan; Password=$henkan72;Database=ArchiveAddin";`

The code that doesn't work (called directly after the first function):

```
public void populateClientHistoryDict(SqlConnection conn)
{
            Dictionary<string, string> clientHistoryDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                using (conn)
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                      @"SELECT ClientDirName, ClientEmailDomain FROM ClientHistoryTable;",
                      conn);
                    conn.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string clientDir = reader.GetString(0);
                            string clientEmail = reader.GetString(1);
                            clientHistoryDict.Add(clientEmail, clientDir);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No rows found in ClientHistoryTable", "Rows Not Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientHistoryTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception while accessing ClientHistoryTable: {0}", ex), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
}
```

The exception I get is this:
Exception while accessing ClientHistoryTable: System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initalized. etc. etc.  at ProgramName.ClassName.populateClientHistoryDict(SqlConnection conn) on line 241.  (The line where I call conn.Open();  in the second function.

Also for reference I have another function where I connect to the db to see if it exists.  It works with the ClientTable but not the ClientHistoryTable.  Why would that be?  They are exactly the same.

Any ideas?  I've dealt with the error before but never when it was working for one table and not another.  I have no idea why I wouldn't get this error on the second attempt to reach a table and not the first.

Thanks

EDIT:

Oddly, if I put `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString)` inside of `populateClientHistoryDict()` it works.  I did the same with `populateClientDict()` and it worked too, but it already did.  Why doesn't it work if I pass in the connection to those two functions, but works if I instantiate the connection inside of the functions?  Can only one SqlConnection be used for one access of the database?  I'm violating DRY by adding the connection string in each function, but I can't get it to work with this code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
if (checkDatabaseExists())
{
    populateClientDict(conn);
    populateClientHistoryDict(conn);
}
```

The First function works, but not the second.  And as I said if I remove the arguments and put the connection objects inside the functions it works fine.  Why is this?  Am I correct about one SqlConnection per access?  If I add a second `SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connString);` and then passed it to `populateClientHistoryDict(conn2)` it works again, seems I am right about one connection object per use.  Is that correct?  Or am I mistaken?

Here is the working code calling those functions:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connString);
if (checkDatabaseExists())
{
    populateClientDict(conn);
    populateClientHistoryDict(conn2);
}
```

Seems I may have answered my own questions, but feedback would still help a lot, and I will still accept any good answers that restate what I said and elaborate a bit, or correct what I said and elaborate a bit as well.

Also I may as well ask, is it a huge deal I'm not using the app settings xml for connection strings and referencing them with ConfigurationManager?  I only have one DB I connect to, and only twice.  Seems unnecessary.  Although I will be eventaully doing CRUD operations on the two tables via  a Form, but that's another matter.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems one SqlConnection object instantiated, is only good for a single connection, even if closed.  By creating a second SqlConnection object with the same connection string, and passing that to the second function, it worked.